# Opening a File and putting the data into a double vector, C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I'm a beginner to C++, in the beginning of my program, I am trying to have data from a csv file be input into a double vector.

However, when I tried running the program, I keep getting the 'row' and 'col' are not declared in this scope.

I tried to solve this by putting ' int row; int col; ' above 'string input [row][col];'  to try and solve the problem.
But then I get the error "array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token".

I'm wondering how to solve this problem? Or if there is maybe something I am missing that I didn't realize.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


string input[row][col];
const int ROW = 10;
const int COL = 4;
string input[ROW][COL];
const string datatable = "table2.csv";
string line;
int col = 0;
int row = 0;


void readCSV()   ////this is the function to read the file
{
    ifstream file(datatable);   ///opens file
    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        istringstream iss(line); //takes out white
        string result;
        while (getline(iss, result, ','))
        {
            input[row][col] = result; // creates string for element
            col = col + 1;
        }
        row = row + 1;
        col = 0;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you do not take this as being offensive, but there are multiple errors here.

I'll start off by commenting your code to show where the errors are, and then I will get into explaining the problems:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


string input[row][col]; /* <- "row" and "col" are not yet defined */
const int ROW = 10;
const int COL = 4;
string input[ROW][COL]; /* <- you already have a variable named "input" */
const string datatable = "table2.csv";
string line;
int col = 0;
int row = 0;


void readCSV()
{
    ifstream file(datatable);   ///opens file
    while (getline(file, line)) /* <- no check to make sure max rows are not exceeded */
    {
        istringstream iss(line); //takes out white
        string result;
        while (getline(iss, result, ',')) /* No check to make sure max columns are not exceeded */
        {
            input[row][col] = result; // creates string for element
            col = col + 1;
        }
        row = row + 1;
        col = 0;

    }
```

To revise these, I would do the following:

1. I would delete `string input[row][col]` as that is defined later on properly.
2. I would change `while (getline(file, line))` to `while (getline(file, line) && row < ROW)`
3. I would change `while (getline(iss, result, ','))` to `while (getline(iss, result, ',') && col < COL)`

I am not guaranteeing that these are the only problems and that the code will run perfectly after correcting these issues. (*I rarely program in C++ anymore, so I cannot make that guarantee with 100% confidence*.) However, these are just some initial errors/problems that I am noticing right off the bat.

---

**Edit**: Just as an additional note, I agree with another answer that was posted (it seems to be deleted now) which recommended changing `ROW` and `COL` to preprocessor definitions/macros. For example, `const int ROW = 10` would become `#define ROW 10` and `const int COL = 4` would become `#define COL 4`. In your example here, it would not cause a huge change, but the benefit here is that `ROW` and `COL` will not occupy memory space as variables then, because the compiler will replace all references to `COL` and `ROW` with the literal defined values of 4 and 10 respectively.

That is somewhat of a preference based suggestion, though, so feel free to do whatever you feel more comfortable with. Just based on the snippet of code you provided, you probably will not see any performance change anyway. However, I wanted to give my personal opinion on this since another answer suggested it.

Answer (score 0):

At a bare minimum, you need to delete the first

```
string input[row][col];
```

After all ,`input` is declared (correctly) a few lines down.